# CSS Unordered lists not displaying

Tags: html, css

I have Sasha Vodnik HTML5 and CSS3 book and I'm trying to create bullet points for my unordered lists. Now I have literally tried a good 15+ variations to the ul styling rules and selectors/declarations. I've tried putting `article ul{}` instead of `ul{}`, I have tried using display in the `<article> display: list-item; </article>` I've also tried changing the color, position, and everything I could think of. Why are the bullets not displaying? Apologies if it's blatently obvious, I'm still trying to learn CSS style and order of precedence. I can not really find anything on what order you should put your style rules especially in the book, so I'm trying to put it in the order of the html document. Thank you for any insight you can share. Also when I try to set the reset styles it collapses & condenses my whole document. Does this mean if I do not set the border, margin, and padding for each of these, that it will be set to 0?

```css
  html {
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  h1, h2, h3 {
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
  }

  .container {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }

  header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: .4em;
  }

  h1 {
    color: #EADCDC;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    font-size: 5em;
    text-shadow:2px -2px 4px black;

  }

  body {
    background-color: #dee9f9;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

  h2 {
    color: slategray;
    font-size: 3em;
  }

  article {
    background-color: ivory;
    padding: 3%;
  }

  h3 {
    color: teal;
    font-size: 2em;
  }

  /* paragraph elements */
  p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
  }

  .accent {
      text-decoration: underline;
      text-align: center;
  }
  ul {
    list-style: disc;
    list-style-position: outside;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
  }

  aside {
    color: rgb(189, 204, 212);
    background-color: #EADCDC;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 2%;
    margin: 2%;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black; 
    border-radius: 30px;
    float: right;

  }

  footer {
    padding: 0.6em;
    color: ivory;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    text-align: center;
  }
  footer p {
    margin: .4em;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Campus Band Battle</h1>
  </header>
  <aside>
    <h2 class="accent"> ALL AGES EVENT</h2>
    <h3>WHEN</h3>
    <p>June 8th</p>
    <p>8 pm-12pm</p>
    <h3>WHERE</h3>
    <p>Student Union Auditorium</p>
    <p>1234 Learning circle, Sunshine, NV</p>
    <p>Featuring Band XYZ, Band ABCD</p>
  </aside>
  <article>
    <h3>Advance Tickets</h3>
    <p>$18 General</p>
    <p>$36 VIP</p>
    <p>Group rates available on site</p>

    <h3>SPONSORS</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Adventure Works</li>
      <li>Charleston Ski House</li>
      <li>Contoso Ltd.</li>
      <li>Fifth Coffee</li>
      <li>Trotter's Travel</li>
      <li>School of Fine Art</li>
      <li>The Phone Company</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>BENEFITTING</h3>
    <p>The School of Music</p>
    <p>Arts and Entertainment Council</p>
  </article>
  <footer>
    <p> www.123BandBattle.org</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? The title says "unordered lists not displaying" but the code snippet clearly displays the list items. Is this regarding a specific style concern? A spacing or/and padding? You don't have to apologize for asking a question, but you'd need to make it easy to answer.

Comment: I don't understand your question, what's the problem here ?

Comment: The bullets don't display when I run the html file, but everything else works.

Comment: So my questions are why is the bullets not displaying for my unordered list? Does it have something to do with the order I'm putting my style rules in? From everything I've found online it looks to be in the correct format so I'm confused as to why it's not working/displaying . Also do I have to put article in front of the ul styling rule like this ```article ul {...}``` ?

Comment: I just ran the code snippet down at the bottom of my code and it worked, so now I want to does this have something to do with safari? I'm using Visual Studio Code and I have both files saved to a folder in my desktop. Now when I run the html file and safari pops up the bullets do not show. Is there a reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

1.Hi it's look like ul is display correctly, a small bullets at the beginning of every list-item (li) is the natural behavior of unordered list.

2.some elements have default padding/margin, if you set them to 0 the elements won't have extra space around them.

Comment: Why though when I run this html file from my desktop on chrome or safari they do not display? That seems to be the problem I guess I'm having, this whole time I thought it was not working but on here it does...

Comment: Do you have <doctype html> , <head> and <body> tags as require in the html document? ,here there is <div class="container"> as the parent...